# How to compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{(\sin x)^2-x^2}{x^4}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a problem with this limit, I don't know what method to use. I have no idea how to compute it.
It's possible to resolve this limit with the developments of McLaurin?
Can you explain the method and the steps used? Thanks

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{(\sin x)^2-x^2}{x^4}\right)$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Since $\sin^{2}(x)$ converges everywhere to its series expansion (i.e., analytic) you know that you can kill the $-x^2$ in the numerator via the expression for the series of $\sin^{2}(x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could very well use the series expansion of the function at $0$. Note that 
$$
\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\dots
$$
so 
$$
\sin^2(x)=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\text{ higher order terms}
$$
so 
$$
\sin^2(x)-x^2=-\frac{x^4}{3}+\text{ higher order terms}
$$
so 
$$
\frac{\sin^2(x)-x^2}{x^4}=-\frac{1}{3}+\text{ higher order terms}
$$
so 
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2(x)-x^2}{x^4}=?
$$

Comment: fixed, thanks for the correction

Comment: I dont understand the second step: why is $x^2 -\frac{x^4}{3}$

Comment: @Amarildo Square the series expression for $\sin(x)$. You'll get the $x^2$ term by multiplying $x$ and $x$. You'll get two $x^4$ terms by multiplying $x$ and $-x^3/3!$, which gives you the term $2\cdot x\cdot -x^3/3!=-x^4/3$.

Comment: the result with $x^6/36$ delete it right because its too big?

Comment: Exactly, the higher order terms go away as $x\to0$

Comment: I understand now thank you so much :)

Comment: @Amarildo L'Hopital is easier imo.

Comment: @addy2012 i see but i prefer to use McLaurin development when i can :)

Comment: Pedagogically, the series actually shows what's going on though. Near zero, the series tells you the behavior of sin, which lets you deduce the behavior of the function above. L'Hopital hides this. Also, every step above was either squaring a series or simple algebraic maneuvers; it doesn't get much more simple than that

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sin x)^2-x^2}{x^4}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}-x^2}{x^4}$$
$$=\frac 12\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 2x-2x^2}{x^4}$$
Using L'Hospital's rule for $\frac{0}{0}$ form four times, one should get
$$=\frac 12\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-2^4\cos 2x}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}$$

$$=-\frac{16\cos 0}{48}=\color{red}{-\frac 13}$$

Comment: $16/48\neq 1/2$

Comment: @bburGsamohT: thanks for observation

Answer (score 2):

You can get there very easily by multiple application of the $\frac{0}{0}$ L'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2 x - x^2}{x^4} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(2x) - 2x}{4x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\cos(2x) - 2}{12x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-4\sin(2x)}{24x}  = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-8\cos(2x)}{24} = -\frac{1}{3}  $$

Comment: The last use of L'Hospital's rule is not permitted; the form is not 0/0.

Comment: @BernardMasse No that was a notation mistake, i did not remove the -2 from the numerator